# Flutter: android_alarm_manager plugin not working when app restarts

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alarms, flutter-plugin

I have set up the plugin according to pub.dev, it is working when the app is opened the first time, and if I do not close the app, it works great. 
But the callback not trigged after I close the app and open it again.

All the settings in https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager have been all set.
I've debugged in the android project, the method is called to java code correctly, but no callback triggered...

```dart
void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
  await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(const Duration(seconds: 5), 
  helloAlarmID, printHello);
}
```